# To use Custom template or not to use custom template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

If we deploy through Azure DevOps a VM, would it be better to deploy the latest VM SKU as this would be updated as far as updates and Patching then add required software or create a custom template and update template regularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security team might well prefer the latest version to be deployed (and then you would need to keep it up to date on your own customizations with a custom script extension) - as it takes away worries of whether or not security fixes have been applied.

There are two reasons I might not want to do that:

1. It's too complicated to keep a "canned" VM image customized by script. These days that *can* happen, but it's becoming less common.
2. Your software is old and/or not well maintained, and is vulnerable to being broken by unannounced updates.

Comment: Guac,  I have 7 images and 300 Vms my concern is with this approached the build time would be long just  us sure they both have a compelling reasons. But just wanted to know what the best practice or tradition is.

Comment: There is certainly a balance to be struck between maintenance, security, cost, time. I don't know that you'll find a best practice that covers all of it neatly, although I enjoy the discussion!